# fpdf/php text area not bringing end of lines through

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fpdf

I have an HTML document that has a `form`. Parts of the form are text areas where I want the inputter to enter details on several lines.  "Description".

```js
function myJSscript() {
    var description = document.getElementById('description').value;  
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("action", "upload_file.php");
    form.setAttribute("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
    form.setAttribute("method", "POST");
    form.setAttribute("target", "_self");
    form.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="description" value="' + description + '"/>'
    form.submit();
}
```

```html
HTML code

<form name="dform" id="t1">
    <textarea rows="5" name="description" id="description" class="tbox2"></textarea>
    <input type="button" class="submitblue" value="Submit" onclick="myjscript()">
</form>
```

in my upload_file.php

I want to add the textarea to a multicell, but no matter what I try (eg nl2br) it always comes through as a single string of text.  even echoing the value to screen shows no `<br />` or `\n` tags.   HELP!

Here is the PHP Line that writes the textarea to a multicell

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0, 5, $_POST['description']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `<textarea>` (multiple lines) in your HTML and `<input>` (one line) in JavaScript that removes the linebreaks.